# Pattern matching: Times[a_] vs Times[a__]

Tags: pattern-matching

I don't understand why

```
 MatchQ[
  HoldComplete[Times[3, 2, 2]],
  HoldComplete[Times[a_]]
  ]
```

is returning True. I thought that `Times[a_]` would match only one argument (i.e. `Times[3]`) while `Times[a__]` would match all of them.

Edited question: is there a way I can force it to match only where only one argument is present? My first thought would be to use `;/`

Comment: There is some mention of this in the ref guide under `Flat`.

Comment: This has to do with the `Flat` attribute of `Times`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The observed behaviour will appear in any expression whose symbolic head has the attribute `Flat`.

Under normal circumstances, with no attributes in play, we see the usual expected behaviour:

```
MatchQ[f[1], f[1]]            (* True *)
MatchQ[f[1], f[a_]]           (* True *)
MatchQ[f[1], f[f[1]]]         (* False *)
MatchQ[f[1], f[f[a_]]]        (* False *)
MatchQ[f[1, 2, 3], f[a_]]     (* False *)
```

But when we introduce the `Flat` attribute, our normal intuition no longer holds:

```
SetAttributes[g, Flat]

MatchQ[g[1], g[1]]            (* True *)
MatchQ[g[1], g[a_]]           (* True *)
MatchQ[g[1], g[g[1]]]         (* True *)
MatchQ[g[1], g[g[a_]]]        (* True *)
MatchQ[g[1, 2, 3], g[a_]]     (* True *)
```

**What is happening?**

The purpose of `Flat` is to flatten out any nested expressions.  That is, `g[g[1, 2, 3]]` is to be treated as equivalent to `g[1, 2, 3]`.  The key point is that this equivalence works both ways.  So when we ask whether `g[1, 2, 3]` matches the pattern `g[a_]`, then this is equivalent to asking whether `g[g[1, 2, 3]]` matches `g[a_]`.  Which of course it does.  That is why the `MatchQ` expression in the question returns `True`.  As does `MatchQ[g[g[g[g[g[1, 2, 3]]]]], g[a_]]`

**Can we turn it off?**

A simple way to perform the exact match requested by the question is to temporarily remove the `Flat` attribute from `Times`.  `Block` will strip `Times` of all of its attributes:

```
Block[{Times}
, MatchQ[
    HoldComplete[Times[3, 2, 2]]
  , HoldComplete[Times[a_]]
  ]
]
(* False *)
```

If, for some reason, the application is such that we wish to retain the other attributes of `Times`, we can use `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``:

```
Attributes[Times]
(* {Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected} *)

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Times}
, Unprotect[Times]
; ClearAttributes[Times, Flat]
; Protect[Times]
; { MatchQ[
      HoldComplete[Times[3, 2, 2]]
    , HoldComplete[Times[a_]]
    ]
  , Attributes[Times]
  }
]
(* {False, {Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected}} *)
```

Comment: Nice answer,I have seen `Internal` package for some times, BTW, I'd like to know what's the main purpose (functionality) of `Internal`package? or is there any detailed introduction to this package .:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang The `Internal` package is undocumented, and we use its features at our own risk since it carries no guarantees and could be withdrawn at any time.  As the name implies, it is used internally by the _Mathematica_ implementation.  There is no official documentation on this package, but this forum is rapidly becoming the repository for the collective findings of the community -- whether about [Internal](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=inheritedblock) or many of the other undocumented features.  And even the documented ones too :)

Comment: OK,@WReach thanks very much!:-)

Answer (score 3):

`Times` has attributes `Flat`, `Orderless`, and `OneIdentity` to cater for Associativity and Commutativity.

**These attributes affect patterns**; in your case to ensure that `x_.y_.z_` not only matches the pattern `x`, but also `y` and `z`. This is in line with the *commutative* property of multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

As WReach says in his answer, the issue is with attributes. Another way to turn off the [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat) attribute in pattern matching is to use [`Verbatim`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim):

```
MatchQ[HoldComplete[Times[3, 2, 2]], HoldComplete[Verbatim[Times][_]]]
```

> False

Answer (score 1):

I have found some other ways (than `Block[...]`) to "force" the matching, but with some slight modifications of the code.

**1.** Whatever the choice you make here :

```
{f1, f2} = {Hold, Hold};
```

or

```
{f1, f2} = {HoldComplete, HoldComplete};
```

or

```
{f1, f2} = {Unevaluated, HoldPattern};
```

the two following approaches work (and give the same results) :

-> *Using* **`/;`** : (this is actually the more compact solution)

```
MatchQ[f1[Times[3, 2, 2]], f2[Times[p : __ /; Length@{p} == 1]]]
MatchQ[f1[Times[3, 2, 2]], f2[Times[p : __ /; Length@{p} == 3]]]
(*False*)
(*True*)
```

-> *Using a "trick" with* **`/.`**

```
MatchQ @@ ({f1[Times[3, 2, 2]], f2[Times[a_]]} /. Times -> foo)
MatchQ @@ ({f1[Times[3, 2, 2]], f2[Times[_, _, _]]} /. Times -> foo)
(*False*)
(*True*)
```

*Of course, instead of `Times[_,_,_]` you could use conditional `/;` or even pattern test `?`, to specify how many arguments Times should have (like in the previous solution) but this would produce a longer and less readable code.*

**2.** All the previous code works not only when the arguments are numbers (`Times[3,2,2]`) but also when they are just symbolic variables (`Times[a,b,c]`)

For *symbolic variables* ***only***, this also works :

```
Remove[a, b, c];
(**)
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], _Times?(Length@# == 1 &)]
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], _Times?(Length@# == 3 &)]
(*False*)
(*True*)
```

In comparison, neither this works :

```
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Times[x_, y_, z_]]
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Times[x_, y_]]
MatchQ[Times[a, b, c], Times[x_]]
(*True*)
(*True*)
(*True*)
```

nor the original test :

```
MatchQ[HoldComplete[Times[a, b, c]], HoldComplete[Times[x_, y_, z_]]]
MatchQ[HoldComplete[Times[a, b, c]], HoldComplete[Times[x_]]]
(*True*)
(*True*)
```